# BBEdit AppleScript for reformatting multiple files

Tags: applescript, bbedit

I'm looking to write an Applescript which will utilize BBEdit — loop through a ton of HTML files and autoformat them (so the indentation is easier to read).

So far I have:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    open {file "Macintosh HD:TEST DIRECTORY:testfile copy 2.html"} with LF translation
    (format mode hierarchical)
    beep 
    display alert "Finished!"
end tell
```

This applies the transformation to a single file, but has anyone got any suggestions how to apply this to an unknown number of HTML files?

Comment: Where are you getting the list of files from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it; the trick is that you want to loop through the files returned by `open`.  Thus, you need something like this:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    set docs to open LIST_OF_FILES with LF translation
    repeat with doc in docs
        -- format doc
        save doc
    end repeat
    beep -- Or even `say "Finished!" without waiting until completion`
         -- if you want your computer to talk to you
    display alert "Finished!"
end tell
```

As you can see, all you need to do is place your formatting code inside this loop (and don't forget to save the files!); the loop will set `doc` to each element of the list `docs` in turn, and run the body with that element.  If you're not sure how to select the files, one way is `choose file with multiple selections allowed`; this will pop up a dialog box which will allow you to select as many files as you want.  To use it, just replace `LIST_OF_FILES` with `(choose file with multiple selections allowed)`.

Answer (score 0):

BBEdit will perform a find/replace on any group of files you want. Just hit command+shift+f to bring up Multi-File Search instead of the basic find/replace window.

If you have more than one set of find/replace commands that you need to execute at the same time, you need a Text Factory. See here for details on how to set one up: http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsexercise.html

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Text Factory feature for this. Under "File > New > Text Factory". Any operation you can perform on a single file can be done on any number of files and you can save the operation for future use.